# VBA errors when trying to access a different workbook

Tags: excel, vba

So, I'm trying to open some files, dynamically get the range I need and then load some data.
Problem is, when I try to access the values of the cells, I get an error. I've tried using ".Range", ive tried using ".Cells" and neither seems to be working.
If you guys could help me that would be great!

This is the Function:

```
Private Sub ReadDataFromFile(filePath As String, Optional importSheetName As String, Optional exportSheetName As String)
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim src As Workbook
    
    ' OPEN THE SOURCE EXCEL WORKBOOK IN "READ ONLY MODE".
    Set src = Workbooks.Open(filePath, True, True)
    
    ' GET THE TOTAL ROWS FROM THE SOURCE WORKBOOK.
    Dim fRow As Long
    lRow = 4
    
    While src.Worksheets("Stock_List").Cells(1, fRow).Value <> "PROJECT" 'The cell where the data ends has "PROJECT" inside of it which is what I use to find the range
        fRow = fRow + 1
    Wend
    
    fRow = fRow - 1
    
    ' CLOSE THE SOURCE FILE.
    src.Close False             ' FALSE - DON'T SAVE THE SOURCE FILE.
    Set src = Nothing
    
ErrHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

(The error that pops up is "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error" at the start of the While loop)

Comment: Does the worksheet "Stock_List" exist in the opened workbook?

Comment: Yes it does, when I tried a different function that copies the entire range to a worksheet in my target workbook, it worked just fine, but accessing this src workbook cell by cell seems to be a problem

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that you do not have `Option Explicit` set at the top of your module ... hence the VBE is not telling you that you are using the undeclared variable `lRow` just below the declaration (ie `Dim`) of the variable `fRow` ... change `lRow` to `fRow` and you're good to go!

Strongly recommend always including `Option Explicit` at the top of every module ... not including it just hides (often hard to find) errors.